# Render a view after post request in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, routes

I am sending a post request to server via ajax:

**result.ejs**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/result",
    data: { score: score, rank: rank, name: name, email: email, historyLog: historyLog }
  });
```

I am reciveing it and saving data to the database:

**resultController.js**

```
app.post('/result', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {

      var user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        score: req.body.score,
        rank: req.body.rank,
        historyLog: req.body.historyLog
      });

      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('User saved successfully!');

      });


  });
```

After saving it I want to render a new view, and I can't get it working.
I have tried adding this after the save function:

`res.redirect('page')`, `res.render('page')`, setting headers html/text

None of the above is working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX is usually used precisely when you *don't* want to navigate elsewhere, but talk to the server in the background instead. To still do it your way, use `res.send("done");` *inside* the save callback, right after `console.log('User saved successfully!);`, then add this to your ajax request:

```
success: function () { window.location.href = "/page"; }
```

A much simpler way to implement the entire process is to use a `<form method="post" action="/result">` and submit it.

Comment: Yes, using a form would be much easier but I just can't implement it in my case, but adding this function to ajax success did the trick! +1

Answer (score 1):

This is working fine to post.
Better use form to post.

```
app.post('/result', function(req, res) {

   new user({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    score: req.body.score,
    rank: req.body.rank,
    historyLog: req.body.historyLog
  }).save(function(err,doc) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else { res.render('pagename.ejs'); }
    console.log('User saved successfully!',doc);
   }); });
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: This answer is not only for one person.In Future anyone may refer this.So when you are answering please add explanation

Answer (score -1):

If you want to render page after saving - add it in saving callback, like this

```html
app.post('/result', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {

      var user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        score: req.body.score,
        rank: req.body.rank,
        historyLog: req.body.historyLog
      });

      user.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('User saved successfully!');
        res.render('page');//ADD HERE redirect o render
      });


  });
```

Comment: But will this cause a new view to be rendered? The browser is requesting `/result` via AJAX, which means the reply is still discarded, no matter where or how it is generated.

Comment: if you use ajax, you need send some info in response (json or just status 200) and then make a redirect (or show something) on client side acording to this response